# A maven mojo to create os links (ln -s or junctions)

Tags: maven-2

Do you know any maven plugin/mojo able to do junction points or links ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about the maven junction plugin? http://pyx4j.com/snapshot/pyx4j/pyx4j-maven-plugins/maven-junction-plugin/introduction.html
Seems compatible with win and *nix os

Comment: Far better answer than previous one. Besides, nice to see you here (too sad there is not the slightest social features in StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're asking for but the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) should be able to do that (have a look at [`exec:exec`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html)).